# Being able to all abilities of Kendo UI Model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

I am newbie in Kendo UI world. I have read the book named "Learning Kendo UI Web Development". I have an opinion and a little skills to use it.
However I still wonder some points about the tools. For example, I want to use all abilities of Kendo Model like toJson or etc.
Also,I think that kendoGrid() and data() function serves many easinesses. I need a documentation about the usage of these two useful methods. I want to learn these all abilities about the tool. The documentation of the product is not enough; I cannot reach some points in it; and their forum is commercial for asking a question.

Comment: That's a quite broad question... If you have specific issues, with some code along them, people here will be able to help you and explain why things work that way. Otherwise, it's just too much to explain

Comment: You can follow the product documentation and start implementing the widgets. If gets any issue then add very specific questions with implemented codes. That would be helpful.:)